# How to show an item after every three elements using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count

I am trying to show an item after every three `{{ $image->title }}`, 
but my method used creates a bit delay in loading the page, i.e. when I remove `<div class='extra'>`, there is reduction of 200ms.

Is there any best alternate method for below?

```
@foreach( $images as $index =>$image)  
 <div>
   {{ $image->title }}
 </div>
  @if( count($images) > 0 && $index != 0 && ($index % 3) == 0 )
    <div class="extra">
      Item to show after three Image Titles
    </div>
  @endif    
@endforeach
```

Comment: `count($images) > 0` has no purpose. if you are already inside of loop that means count is automatically > 0

Comment: Only way to reduce time is you can pass every third $image from controller. And there will be no need to set third item condition in blade.

Comment: i.e Try to filter every third item in controller.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat that literally changes nothing. Blade file is still converted to php  and `$index % 3` will have the same speed when done in controller vs blade file.

Comment: If it takes too long then problem is most likely in `<div class="extra">` if it contains something else besides text you posted here. This is very simple code and there is no much place for performance gain except removing `count`

Comment: @NoOorZ24 even when `$index != 0 && ($index % 3) == 0` removed, it gives good speed

Comment: @AnonymousGirl So I understand correctly that rendering `div` without condition is faster than rendering every 3rd `div`?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 yes same

Comment: @AnonymousGirl Is it faster or is it same? Does that div contain something else than posted here? Does removing div while keeping condition make it run noticeably faster?

Comment: keeping the division and just removing only `$index != 0 && ($index % 3) == 0` reduces the load time. Also even if **division class extra** has nothing or it is not there, no affect, only effect when if condition

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has its own Blade $loop variable that is meant to help you with this check out the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

In your case something like this makes more sense

```
 @foreach( $images as $index =>$image)  
 <div>
   {{ $image->title }}
 </div>
  @if( $loop->iteration % 3) // this can be $loop->index but im not sure what you need
    <div class="extra">
      Item to show after three Image Titles
    </div>
  @endif    
@endforeach
```

Comment: It works though but it has not reduced the timing

Comment: Then I dont think you can reduce it then, since doing this in the controller or blade will return the same timing, as the comments under the questions said